# JPanel won't get painted with paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, paintcomponent

It won't paint at all, any ideas?
Nothing is displayed on the back panel, how do I get to paint with the mouseDragged event?

I can't even display a single line with that... Here's the source code.. I added the Jbutton just to see if the Panel was actually being displayed

```
public class pinta extends JFrame {

HandlerClass handler=new HandlerClass();
    JPanel back=new JPanel();
    public pinta(){
        setSize(500,500);
        setResizable(true);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        back.setBackground(Color.white);
        back.setSize(500,500);
        this.add(back);
        back.add(new JButton("test"));
        back.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
        back.setOpaque(true);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }    

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.fillOval(100, 100, 20, 10);
        g2d.setPaintMode();
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));

    }

    public class HandlerClass implements MouseMotionListener{
        int x, y;

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }
        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }
        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }
        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            x=e.getX();
            y=e.getY(); 
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){ 
        }

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`JFrame` does not have a method call `paintComponent`.  If you used the `@Override` annotation, the compiler would have failed.

Also note, you are calling `super.paintComponents` - Notice the "s" at the end, this should have being an interactor of problems

`JComponent` (or `JPanel` which extends `JComponent`) is what you're after.

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

I should also mention that `back.setSize(500,500)` is irrelevant, as the layout manager will decide what size it wants to make the component

Comment: You seem to be on a roll today. Every question I've looked at it's _you_.I guess it's just one of those days :D

Comment: @peeskillet Slow day at work...did I say that out loud?